# meta tags in web page in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

In visual studio 2003 meta tags are listed in the head section itself.

Where can I find the meta tags in an aspx page in visual studio 2005?

Also is it possible to change the html parser in visual studio 2003 to XHTML parser as in visual studio 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parsing/design view was rewritten in Visual Studio 2005, there is no way to get that functionality in 2003. Meta tags should always go into the head section, Visual Studio 2005 just doesn't add all those default meta tags like Visual Studio 2003 did (which is a good thing).

Here is more information about the structure of an HTML file:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html